# Contour Integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

Evaluate:

1. $\int_C \hat{z} dz$ where $C$ is the straight line from $i$ to $2-i$.
2. $\int_C \frac{dz}{z}$ where $C$ is the straight line from $3$ to $4i$
3. $\int_C (z-z_0)^{n-1}dz $ for any integer $n$, where C is the contour once around the circle $|z-z_0|=1$.

I know that $z=x+iy$, so $\hat{z}=x-iy$. so for the first part, $\int (x-iy)dz$ from $i$ to $2-i$, but I don't know if to integrate with respect to $dx$ or $dy$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is the description of the contour on which you are integrating.  For example, the straight line from $z=i$ to $z=2-i$ is described by

$$z=i (1-t) + (2-i) t$$

where $t \in [0,1]$.  Then equating real and imaginary parts, $x=2 t$, $y=1-2 t$.  Also, $dz = 2 (1-i) dt$.  The first integral is then

$$\int_0^1 (2 t - i (1-2 t)) (2 (1-i)) \, dt$$

You can evaluate this.

Comment: how did you get dz=2(1-i)dt?

Comment: on #2 I've got that x=3(1-t) and y=4t. so when I set up the integral for 1/z dz I'll have 1/(3(1-t)+i(4t)(...)dt and the (...) is for dz, but I don't know how to get that.

Comment: @xfitpi The derivative of $at + b$ for constants $a$, $b$ is $a$.

Comment: @AymanHourieh I still do not understand your abbreviated step on the derivative

Comment: @xfitpi $dz = \frac{dz}{dt} dt$. And $\frac{dz}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}\left( i + t(2-2i) \right) = 2-2i$. Does it make sense now?

Comment: @AymanHourieh, I'm trying to calculate the derivative of that for dz, but I can't get it to equal 2-2i.  However, after I did the integral you wrote the very first time, and that did =2-2i.

Comment: @xfitpi: $z=i(1-t) + (2-i) t = i + (2-2 i) t$ implies that $dz = (2-2 i) dt$.

Comment: @xfitpi: for #2, you have the correct expression for $x$ and $y$.  The integral is then (-3 + 4 i)$$\int_0^1 \frac{dt}{3+(-3+4 i)t}$$.  Again, you can do this.